# Dynamically allocate pointer to array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, malloc

I have long used pointers to arrays in C programs of the form:

```
int (*myarray)[2] = (int (*)[2]) malloc(n*sizeof(int[2]));
```

However, how can I do this in C++ using new? Can I do this?

```
int (*myarray)[2] = (int (*)[2]) new int[n][2];
```

EDIT:

Looks like my original post was incomplete and confusing. Here is a code snippet that I compiled and tested which appears to do the right thing but I wanted to confirm from C++ experts that I was using an appropriate C++ construct.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  int n=5;
  int (*A)[2] = new int[n][2];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      A[i][j] = 2*i+j;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    std::cout << A[i][0] << " " << A[i][1] << "\n";

  delete myarray;
```

}

Comment: _'Can I do this?'_ What does [**the compiler actually tell you**](http://ideone.com/W2XGTs)? I'm afraid [**computer say's no!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n_Ty_72Qds)

Comment: If you use a cast like above to make something compile, you are doing something wrong. As a C++ beginner, forget the fact that these C-style casts exist, there are almost zero cases where it really is needed.

Comment: Have you tried using `int (*myarray)[2] = new int[n][2];`?

Comment: Do you want an array of pointers or a dynamically allocated pointer?

Comment: Actually, @πάντα ῥεῖ, the compiler says "yes", as long as you remember to set n to a positive integer before you call new int[n][2].  But I think the definition of myarray as shown above is still a bad idea.

Comment: @DavidK _'... as long as you remember to set ...'_ Not for the actual sample I linked ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : http://ideone.com/0sYUhC (cut and pasted your code into a new window and inserted the line `int n = 10;`).

Comment: @DavidK That doesn't make this a better question. My intend was to animate the OP to post a complete & compilable sample.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : Good goal. Unfortunately, I was distracted by the nature of the compiler failure and missed the point. Perhaps the OP had a similar reaction. In any case, it would be interesting to know if OP ever actually tried compiling that line of code in any context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joys of using C++ and STL is you get a vector class that provides array like behaviour.
This also makes it easier to manage and read...

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > myarray(n);
```

If you don't want to use the STL then there is always...

```
typedef int intarray[2];
intarray* ints = new intarray[n];
ints[0][0] = 1;
...
ints[n-1][1] = 6;
```

I personally would write an extra line of code if it made the code easier to read.

Comment: You need `vector<vector<int>> myarray(n, vector<int>(2))` in order to create a vector of vectors of two integers. However, use `array<int,2>` instead, as explained above.

Comment: Wouldn't vector of vectors be overkill for this need? The typedef of a fixed array and declaring and allocating pointer to this type is nice way of clarifying intent while keeping overhead of the data structure low.

Answer (score 2):

I think the clearest way to do what you ask for is to use a typedef for the array:

```
typedef int array_t[2];
array_t* yourarray = new array_t[n];
```

Don't do that though, because it requires doing manual memory management and that tends to be tedious, error-prone and brittle, in particular with respect to exception safety. Instead, take a look at the `std::array` class template (new in C++11, but otherwise available via Boost) and at the `std::vector` class template.

To clarify the different between storing `std::vector` and `std::array` in a container, the latter is typically more efficient when there is a small and fixed number of elements involved. The reason is that the array class doesn't allocate things dynamically as the vector does. For that, vector needs three pointers (beginning, end of used storage and end of allocated storage) plus of course the storage for the data itself (plus maybe some overhead induced by the allocator) all of which need to be loaded into the CPU cache for use. Considering an LP64 system, that would require 32 bytes to store 8 bytes of data, compared to just 8 bytes using `std::array`.

Comment: The only thing to consider of course is if your code is compiled on C++ 11 compliant compilers, so I use vector purely as a portable example.
If you want fixed size arrays and you support C++ 11 then std::array is the answer.

Comment: Well, read again: For older C++ compilers you just throw in Boost and use `boost::array`.